# C++ | Could not deduce template argument for T | Void function with no arguments (display() )

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am creating a dynamic Que in C++ with templates for further practice. Most important functions seem to work just fine except for last 2 I have defined - void functions with no arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class DynamicQueue
{
private:
// Structure for the queue nodes
struct QueueNode
{
    T value;       // Value in a node
    QueueNode *next;    // Pointer to the next node
};
QueueNode *top;      // The top of the queue
QueueNode *bottom;     // The bottom of the queue
int numItems;          // Number of items in the queue
public:
DynamicQueue() {
    top = nullptr;
    bottom = nullptr;
    numItems = 0;
}
~DynamicQueue() {
    delete[] top;
    delete[] bottom;
}
template <typename T>
    bool isEmpty() const {
    bool empty;
    if (numItems > 0)
        empty = false;
    else
        empty = true;
}
template <typename T>
void display() const {
        QueueNode* temp = top;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            cout << temp->value << endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
}
template <typename T>
void clear() {
    T temp;
    while (!isEmpty()) {
        dequeue(data);
    }
}
};
```

There is an enque and a deque functions that I did not include in the code as they are working just fine.
The main function looks kind of like:

```
int main() {

string str;
int number;

DynamicQueue<string> strQ;
DynamicQueue<int> intQ;

strQ.enqueue("Word number 1");
strQ.enqueue("2");

strQ.dequeue("2");
strQ.display();

intQ.enqueue(1);
intQ.enqueue(2);
int placehold;
intQ.dequeue(placehold);
intQ.display();

strQ.clear();
intQ.clear();

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Compiler produces the following error:

error C2672: 'DynamicQueue::display': no matching overloaded function found

error C2783: 'void DynamicQueue::display(void) const': could not deduce template argument for 'T'

note: see declaration of 'DynamicQueue::display'

I understand that the issue is somewhere in me doing the templates wrong. But I dont seem to understand the correct way of doing it.

(There are the same issues for the clear() function)

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]? Definition of `enqueue` and `dequeue` functions not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a template shadowing issue because you are redeclaring a template *T* over your class methods definition, which is in your case redundant.

It would have been necessary if you had implemented your methods outside your class definition.

Inside class definition:

```
void clear() {
    // Stuff
}
```

Outside:

```
template <typename T>
void DynamicQueue<T>::clear() {
    // Stuff
}
```

The syntax you initially used is a new template declaration specific for a method, for example to enqueue it could be:

```
template<typename... Args>
void enqueue(Args&&... args)
{
    // Create new node
    QueueNode* new_node = new QueueNode();
    bottom->next = new_node;

    new (&(new_node->value)) T(args...);
    bottom = new_node;
}
```

And the outside declaration:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void DynamicQueue<T>::enqueue(Args&&... args)
{
    // Create new node
    QueueNode* new_node = new QueueNode();
    bottom->next = new_node;

    new (&(new_node->value)) T(args...);
    bottom = new_node;
}
```

but the template argument's name cannot be *T* or you'll have shadowing issue